# Creating a folder inside a folder in google drive android

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to integrate Google drive with my app I have registered my app in Google Developers Console. I got a sample from https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos .By this i am able to create a file,folder in Google drive's root folder but the problem is I couldn't create a file or folder inside an existing folder. In such case i got a toast "Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?" ie I cannot get the driveID

```
public class CreateFolderInFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FOLDER_ID)
            .setResultCallback(idCallback);
}

final ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
             showMessage(result.getStatus().toString());
            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi
                .getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("MyNewFolder").build();
        folder.createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)
                .setResultCallback(createFolderCallback);
    }
};

final ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> createFolderCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while trying to create a folder");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Folder successfully created");
    }
};
}
```

I cannot find any proper documentation for this.
Plz help me where i am going wrong or Whether I Have to include any other permissions

Answer (score 4):

You can take a peek here: in the '[createTree()](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/MainActivity.java#L148)' method, there is a creation of folder within a folder.

There are 3 different drive ID entities in the new Google Drive Android API (GDAA)

1. the object of type DriveID - the one you get from methods and use in your code
2. a string you get from *encodeToString()* and pass to *decodeFromString()* - used to save within the app (caching for instance)
3. a string you get from *getResourceId()* and pass to *fetchDriveId()* - the one you see in the html address of a file.

Both 2 and 3 identifiers are strings, so they may be confused. Identifier 2 is faster when retrieving Drive ID (via decodeFromString()). Identifier 3 is slower to retrieve (via fetchDriveId()), but usefull if you need to take your ID elsewhere (Apps Script, for instance).

Please see also: [SO 21800257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800257/)

Comment: Can I say __public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "CAESABjACiCShczj8lI=";__

Comment: I copied the ID of the folder while it was created

Comment: @seanpj link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

What is EXISTING_FOLDER_ID?  If you are trying to just run the sample straight out without having made any changes, this won't work.

You need to change EXISTING_FOLDER_ID to the resource id of a folder that your app has access to. This could be a folder that your app created in the root.

Comment: Yes i made that EXISTING_FOLDER_ID dynamically with the values of driveid for the folder i am creating but i am getting network error when idCallback function is called

Answer (score 0):

first create folder using creatreeTree()

then run a search query to get id of create `public static ArrayList<ContentValues> search(String prnId, String titl, String mime) {
        ArrayList<ContentValues> gfs = new ArrayList<>();
        if (mGOOSvc != null && mConnected) try {
            // add query conditions, build query
            String qryClause = "'me' in owners and ";
            if (prnId != null) qryClause += "'" + prnId + "' in parents and ";
            if (titl != null) qryClause += "title = '" + titl + "' and ";
            if (mime != null) qryClause += "mimeType = '" + mime + "' and ";
            qryClause = qryClause.substring(0, qryClause.length() - " and ".length());
            Drive.Files.List qry = mGOOSvc.files().list().setQ(qryClause)
                    .setFields("items(id,mimeType,labels/trashed,title),nextPageToken");
            String npTok = null;
            if (qry != null) do {
                FileList gLst = qry.execute();
                if (gLst != null) {
                    for (File gFl : gLst.getItems()) {
                        if (gFl.getLabels().getTrashed()) continue;
                        gfs.add( UT.newCVs(gFl.getTitle(), gFl.getId(), gFl.getMimeType()));
                    }                                                                 //else UT.lg("failed " + gFl.getTitle());
                    npTok = gLst.getNextPageToken();
                    qry.setPageToken(npTok);
                }
            } while (npTok != null && npTok.length() > 0);                     //UT.lg("found " + vlss.size());
        } catch (Exception e) { UT.le(e); }
        return gfs;
    }`

when you get folder id use this code to create folder in folder `  public static ParentReference insertFileIntoFolder(Drive service, String folderId,
                                                        String folderName) throws IOException {

//                        Log.e("founddd",id);
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(new ParentReference().setId(folderId == null ? "root" : folderId)));
            fileMetadata.setTitle(folderName);
            fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

```
        File file  = mGOOSvc.files().insert(fileMetadata).execute();

        System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
        strChildFolder = file.getId();




    return null;
}`
```