# Drive android Api How to delete or Trash and Move a file or folder?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

**seanpj**

Any one know how to **delete file or folder in new Drive android Api** or atleast how to move files to Trash so that user should not see those files in app folder.

Or How to move a file from one folder to another folder?

Comment: Howlin. sorry but that question doesn't cover.    How to move a file from one folder to another folder?

Comment: Others decided, so I have no way to answer officially. Basically, there's nothing in the new GDAA, but in the RESTFul (old) API, there MAY BE a way to switch parents. Never tried it, look here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents and you could use the same principle as with 'delete'. But again, I don't know what surprises will combining the new and old API bring. And be aware that you can have multiple parents with each Drive object.

Comment: If you open this page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get and look at the fields available at the bottom (Try it - Use Fields editor), you will see a list of items available. One of them is 'parents'.

Comment: seanpj Thank you so much for your help. I will try. Can you explain how to fetch a drive file. Because i am confused with all the objects in the GDAA each object gives different id. And when i try to fetch any file It will give "Id Required error". I have gone through Demo Activities but in that they have used Existing_File_Id which they have typed. From where they get that id. I am totally confused please help me.

Comment: In old API it is simple getid will give a id string we can store and later use it to fetch the file. Same thing i want to do using new API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800257/where-did-the-createfromresourceid-go