# Android Google Drive EXISTING_FOLDER_ID,EXISTING_FILE_ID

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

In ***BaseDemoActivity.java*** from Google Drive Demo app

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java

what i have replace in `EXISTING_FOLDER_ID`,`EXISTING_FILE_ID`,`EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME`

Please provide steps to get this values

```
 /**
 * DriveId of an existing folder to be used as a parent folder in
 * folder operations samples.
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "????";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing file to be used in file operation samples..
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "????";

/**
 * Extra for account name.
 */
protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "????";
```

Thanks

Comment: Where you able to find the answer?If yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

The first part, EXISTING_FOLDER_ID,EXISTING_FILE_ID, is answered in [SO 21800257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800257/where-did-the-createfromresourceid-go), but be careful. 
You can't just go to a web Drive interface, create a file, copy/paste its resource id ... Google Drive Android API (GDAA) supports only FILE scope, so only files, folders created by **your** Android App are eligible.

EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME is a name of your Google (gmail) account (myaccount@gmail.com). That's the one you would need here:

```
GoogleApiClient mGac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(contex)
 .addApi(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.API)
 .addScope(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
 .setAccountName(EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME)
 .addConnectionCallbacks(context).addOnConnectionFailedListener(context)
 .build();
```

but I'm not sure the demo even addresses this.
You would use it if your Android App allowed switching between different accounts.