# Fetch the Google drive data from Android App

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am new in Google Drive Integration in Android Application.I need to know whether its possible to read all the contents of google drive from our customize android app.

For Eg: **I need to open an excel file which is stored in google drive & need to fetch the number of rows and columns.**

I have seen the below link:

[Android google drive demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)

But I got confused with the below lines:

```
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FOLDER_ID
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID
```

I have seen below link [Android Google Drive EXISTING_FOLDER_ID,EXISTING_FILE_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466683/android-google-drive-existing-folder-id-existing-file-id)

But no Hope

What am i supposed to add as Drive ID.Its shows null always.

Code:

RetrieveContentsActivity:

```
public class RetrieveContentsActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "RetrieveContentsActivity";

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
                .setResultCallback(idCallback);
    }

    final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
            new RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(
                    RetrieveContentsActivity.this).execute(result.getDriveId());
        }
    };

    final private class RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask
            extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveId, Boolean, String> {

        public RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackgroundConnected(DriveId... params) {
            String contents = null;
            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), params[0]);
            DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult =
                    file.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return null;
            }
            DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                contents = builder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException while reading from the stream", e);
            }

            driveContents.discard(getGoogleApiClient());
            return contents;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result == null) {
                showMessage("Error while reading from the file");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("File contents: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me out how i am supposed to achieve it.Thanks

Comment: In my project,  `DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), params[0]);`  displays error showing unresolved reference: getFile, what should be done? Please hep!

Answer (score 0):

"For Eg: I need to open an excel file which is stored in google drive & need to fetch the number of rows and columns."

Google Drive stores 'stuff' as blobs, so is unable to parse the blob content into rows and columns.

*if* you uploaded excel with convert=true, then it will create a Google Spreadhseet, and then you can use the Spreadsheet API to fetch rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible to fetch any images or any other text file ? Can you please tell how can i get all the files from google drive and list it in my application...

Comment: You can fetch any file type. To list them you use the files.list API call. see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: Thanks Again but can you please tell me how can i get  Drive ID Here  RetrieveContentsActivity.this).execute(result.getDriveId()); show null