# "Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?": Even if EXISTING_FOLDER_ID is set manually

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-drive-android-api

I am having a look at [here](https://github.com/nabinkhadka/android-demos) from github.

I can create a file and a folder successfully by reading the code provided in github. But I am not being able to edit the file or create a file/folder in any specific folder.

**The main problem would be using emulator, but I am not sure. I am using GenyMotion**

I have also copied the ID of a file/folder using

```
showMessage("Created a file in App Folder: "
                    + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
```

and

```
showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
```

lines of code .

Then I changed

```
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "CAESABjACiCShczj8lI=";//changed this
    public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";
```

of BaseActivity. Still I am getting the same output.

**"Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?"**

Can anyone point me what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe that '**result.getDriveFile().getDriveId()**' gives you a '**DriveId**', an ID used by GDAA only. The '**EXISTING_FILE_ID**' refers to another ID, so called **ResourceID**. You have to use that one. See [SO 21800257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800257/where-did-the-createfromresourceid-go). The ResourceId is the original ID used in older RESTful API, and the only one that you can use when referring to the Drive object across different devices (DriveID is device specific). ResourceID can also be seen as a part of the URL address of the object.

BTW. the shortest answer to your question is:

```
result.getDriveFile().getDriveId().getResourceId();
```

But you may get NULL if you're too quick see [SO 22874657](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api) .

Good Luck.

Comment: You may also look at this code that has both GDAA and RESTful APIs implemented side-by-side. It'll give you some idea about the relation of these two (https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo). Another point to consider is, that ResourceId is not immediately available, GDAA must commit the file / folder first,

Comment: How much time does it need to commit? Thank you for the information. That method, __getResourceId()__ helped me alot

Comment: It was one of the reasons I quit GDAA and backed off to RESTful. There was a long discussion about the  requestSync() (grep it here on SO). Some claimed it works, but I could never get reliable results (minutes, hours latency - totally random). Then they added some sync callbacks, but I was already gone from the GDAA world, so I did not pay attention to it anymore.

Comment: Thank you seanpj, can you help me with RESTful? Some helping tutorial? And if it's possible, can you give me your email address? 
Thank you so much once again.

Comment: RESTful's here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/. You will definitely need  at least the playground to test Drive related stuff. See the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I can work at least at the bottom level. Your repo at github was useful.