# cannot get folderId that i just created on google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

```
public class Helpers  extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
SharedPreferences preferences;

private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

public static  String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID;


protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

public static final String folderId = "FOLDER_ID";
public static final String fileName = "folderId";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

final ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult> callback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
            return;
        }

        EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId().toString();
        showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId().toString());

        preferences = getSharedPreferences(fileName , MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(folderId , EXISTING_FOLDER_ID );
        editor.apply();
    }
};

public  void mcreateFolder() {

    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle("SmsSync").build();
    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).createFolder(
            getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).setResultCallback(callback);

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(fileName , MODE_PRIVATE);
    EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = preferences.getString(folderId ,null);
    if (EXISTING_FOLDER_ID == null ) {
        mcreateFolder();

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

public void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}}
```

I want to create a folder when app is installed and than get its ID and save it to sharedprefrences..after that i wanted to create a file inside that folder but when i use pass that folderID to create file inside it than it says 
**"Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?"**

if I use `result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId().getResourceId()`
to get id than its always null.
I am using this code to create folder first which I pasted https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFolderActivity.java

and to create a file inside a folder I am using this guide 
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileInFolderActivity.java
I am passing the `folderiD` that I save and passing it to create file function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not mix DriveId with ResourceId. Both look like strings, but DriveId is different from ResourceId. See [SO 21800257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800257/where-did-the-createfromresourceid-go). Also, ResourceId is not immediately available, see [SO 22874657](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api).

DriveId usually looks like:

> "DriveId:CAESHDBCMW1RVblahblahblahblahMYjAUgssy8yYFRTTNKRU55"

whereas ResourceId is more like:

> "UW2ablahblaghblahNy00Ums0B1mQ"

**UPDATE:**

Since so many developers fight this issue, I'll try to elaborate as deep as my knowledge allows me to.

```
     Google Drive             Google Play Svcs      YourApp
   (up in the cloud)         (on your device)      (on your device)
  +--------------------+      +--------------+     +--------------+         
  | 'id' (RESTful API) | - - -> ResourceId  - - - -> ResourceId   |
  +--------------------+      |  DriveId    - - - -> DriveId      |
                              +--------------+     +--------------+
```

What I'm trying to convey with the artistic expression above is:

- When you create a drive object (folder/file) on your device, GooPlaySvcs will give you the DriveId
- You can use this DriveId for local communication with GooPlaySvcs, you can cache it, etc.
- Per Daniel's comment in SO 21800257 (link above), do not rely on DriveId to be a constant string,
  it supposedly changes upon the object being committed. Use DriveId.equals() (I did not test that)
- Anytime you step outside of the local device (Drive web interface, other apps, YourApp on a different
  device), you need to use ResourceId, which is the only unique ID on the Drive (up in the cloud :-).
- The ResourceId is available to your AFTER GooPlaySvcs commit the object to the Drive. There are
  ways to force it, but it is a different story (search for requestSync()).
- If you decide to grab the ResourceId and use it for RESTfull calls ([delete/trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034693/delete-trash-file-from-android-using-android-gms-drive/29049208#29049208)), be aware 
  of the fact that Google Play Services propagates its changes on a schedule you don't have control
  over (so it seems, see the requestSync() issue again), and your REST/GDAA fight can cause damage
  to your data. GDAA(GooPlayServices) may not be aware of your REST changes for a while. You have
  to manage the synchronization yourself. I admit I failed miserably when I tried.

  Good Luck