# Cannot access Google Drive file

Tags: android, android-activity, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-android-api

I am making a notepad app using `Google Drive`.  Whenever user creates a file in the app, it also creates a file in the `Google Drive`. And user can enter the text and save the file, the unsaved text will get committed whenever the internet is available. I am managing the update and create processes within the app using the `DriveId`.

If the user wants to use the files with the alternative device using my app, for that I also have the option called `DriveId import`.  By clicking the option `DriveId import` user will be prompted with the input box for entering the existing `DriveId`. Using the `DriveId` I thought of opening the files, But it was giving an error.

Then I saw an answer given in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030110/cannot-get-folderid-that-i-just-created-on-google-drive?answertab=active#tab-top) which clearly says `DriveId` can be used only inside the app and device which created the file.

I also found a similar question like mine in here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050204/cannot-access-google-drive-from-2-different-device/29055166) But I can’t get my problem solved. I have taken ResourceId using `result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId().getResourceId()`

How to read the data’s programmatically using the ResourceID? As said in the above answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050204/cannot-access-google-drive-from-2-different-device/29055166) I don’t want to change the track and go into `Drive REST API`. **Is there a way that I can read the data using `Google Drive Android API` ?** I have done all the development process, but in the ending when I try to access from other device it is giving the error. Totally struck.

If I can only read the data using `REST API` any simple code will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally Solved the DriveId Issue without REST API.**

To get `DriveId` on the alternative device. You will need resourceId. You can use following code:-

```
String resourseId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" 

Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(mGoogleApiClient,resourseId).setResultCallback(idCallBack);

private ResultCallBack<DriveApi.DriveResult> idCallBack = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
        msg.Log("onResult");

    DriveId id = driveIdResult.getDriveId(); //Here you go :)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works according to my requirement. Cheers

Comment: @Gaj  You are right, it was the 'fetchDriveId'. My answer was incorrect and I deleted it. As I said, I haven't touched GDAA for a while and I'm getting rusty.