# List files from Google Drive and get downloadUrl for selected file in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to show a list of files the user has on their Google Drive from my Android app and once the user has selected a file, I want to get the `downloadUrl` and the `Bearer token` for that account to give it to my application server to download it.

I have been looking around and it seems very confusing. There are 2 SDKs, [Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) and [Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) (`REST` based) for Google Drive.

I successfully was able to get the list of files and display it using the Android SDK (I did not have to build any UI), and when the user selects a file, I got all the [metadata](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Metadata) about the file but the `downloadUrl`. I did get some links like the `webContentLink` and the `alternateLink`, but it turns out that because the file was not shared, I cannot pass these links to my server to download it.

Upon some more research I found out that the `downloadUrl` is accessible by using the Java SDK. My question is, do I have to build my own UI to display a list of files I obtain? How do I handle the folder hierarchy if I have to build my UI to show these files?

Below is the code which prints the data about the `File`. I have implemented this code based on the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android).

```
public class GoogleDriveActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mService;
public GoogleAccountCredential credential;
public static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 3;
public static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 4;

private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = {DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY};
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_drive);

    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, "abc.test@gmail.com"));

    mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("My Application")
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refreshResults();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            Log.w("gd", "in account picker");
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.W("gd", "in cancelled");
            }
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}

private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(
            credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

private void refreshResults() {
    new GoogleDriveAsync(this).execute();
}

public class GoogleDriveAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private GoogleDriveActivity activity;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            getDataFromApi();

        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
            Log.w("gd", "GPS unavailable");

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            Log.w("gd", "user recoverable");
            activity.startActivityForResult(
                    userRecoverableException.getIntent(),
                    GoogleDriveActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("gd", "general exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    GoogleDriveAsync(GoogleDriveActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of up to 10 file names and IDs.
     *
     * @return List of Strings describing files, or an empty list if no files
     * found.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // Get a list of up to 10 files.
        List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileList result = activity.mService.files().list()
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getItems();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s) (%s)\n",
                        file.getTitle(), file.getId(), file.getDownloadUrl()));
            }
        }
        Log.w("gd", "file info is " + fileInfo.toString());
        return fileInfo;

    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Please see my answer (not the accepted one) for a working sample. The use case is: list all the Google Drive files for the user and when selected one, get the `downloadUrl` and the `access_token` for the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the file/folder outside of your GDAA based app, you need so-called ResourceID. This ResourceId is a string that uniquely identifies the object of Google Drive (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030110/cannot-get-folderid-that-i-just-created-on-google-drive/29049474#29049474))

Turn DriveId into ResourceId:

```
        DriveId driveId = metadata.getDriveId();
        String resourceId = driveId.getResourceId();
```

Once you have ResourceId, you can construct 'download URL' for your server app from it. The ResourceID string is the one found if you go to [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive), select a file/folder and perform *rightbutton > getLink*.
(looks like 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1mQUW2__I_am_the_resource_id')

Just take this string '*0B1mQUW2__I_am_the_resource_id*' to the ['TryIt' playground here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and paste it to the 'fileId' field.

So, the short answer is that you don't need RESTful Api to get the file/folder identifier you can use elsewhere.

Second part of your question, '*How do I handle the folder hierarchy if I have to build my UI to show these files*?' is answered (somewhat) in the 'createTree()/testTree()' methods of MainActivity of these 2 demos ([GDAADemo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo), [RESTDemo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo)). These are the same tasks implemented on the GDAA as well as the REST Apis and the choice depends mainly on the SCOPE your app needs (GDAA supports only the FILE scope, whereas REST supports both the FILE and the DRIVE scopes)

Good Luck

Comment: How coincidental, I was looking at your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795999/how-to-download-file-from-google-drive-using-drive-api, and I was going to answer this question myself. great help though! thank you, it worked.

Comment: A lot of people run into this because GDAA and REST are related, but none of the documentation / demos attempt to show/explain the relation.

Comment: exactly, I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: ... on top of it, even if you can statically map functionality of the two APIs (like CRUD), you will still be running into surprises caused by the internal caching of GDAA - latency/timing issues - but you probably know/guessed that already.

Answer (score 2):

The `Activity`:

```
public class GoogleDriveActivity extends Activity implements
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_SELECT = 2;

private static final String[] SCOPES = { DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE};
private static final String TAG = "GoogleDrive";
private String accountName;


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setupGoogleClient();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);

    AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] list = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    //Getting the first account because that is the primary account for that user
    accountName = list[0].name;

    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent to connect to Google API client " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent to connect to Google API client " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SELECT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                String resourceId = driveId.getResourceId();
                new GoogleDriveAsync(this).execute(resourceId);
            }
            finish();
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Connection to Google API client suspended");
}

private void setupGoogleClient() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}



class GoogleDriveAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private GoogleDriveActivity activity;

    GoogleDriveAsync(GoogleDriveActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            String id = args[0];
            GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
            credential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            com.google.api.services.drive.Drive service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
            File file = service.files().get(id).setFields("downloadUrl").execute();
            if (file != null) {
                String strUrl = file.getDownloadUrl();
                String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, accountName, "oauth2: " + Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
//This is your downloadUrl and token
                Log.w(TAG, "download link is " + strUrl + " and token is " + token);
            }
        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Google Play Services not available to get downloadUrl of selected file");
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            Log.w(TAG, "User authorization error in getting downloadUrl " + userRecoverableException.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Exception in getting downloadUrl " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The `AndroidManifest` (relevant lines) :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<activity
            android:name="com.myapp.GoogleDriveActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=<your-gogole-project-id>"/>
</activity>
```

The `build.gradle` (relevant lines):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0'
```

Comment: Double-check if you really need to go through the REST loops, since I don't know how you're using the 'strUrl'. Wouldn't the ResourceId itself suffice to 'construct' whatever you need on your server (see the 'rightbutton > getLink' blurb above) ?

Comment: The reason for this is that for instance if you're off-line, the GDAA may still give you DriveId and ResourceId (from cache), but REST will blow up since there's no connection. These are the things you have to think about all the time when mixing GDAA with REST.

Comment: @seanpj when I try to access the right button link I get an `Unauthorized` error. basically, I need to give my server a link from which it can download the selected file..but your points about no connection scenario is valid. I will have to put checks around that.