# How to find a google Drive file by ID?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm working on a project where I need to upload a file to google Drive, to download it with another app.

I wanted to use the Drive Id, which I get by creating a file, to find it later, but this seems not to work.

I used an example from Google to get the ID:

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                     driveId =  data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    showMessage("File created with ID: " + driveId);


                }

                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
```

This seemed to work so far, I am getting the Drive ID.

After this, I wanted to test it by using the Example ["Files: get" from the Google Developers-page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get), where I got the following error:

```
 {
    "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "notFound",
     "message": "File not found: CAESABiCASCQ1OnN-VMoAA==",
     "locationType": "other",
     "location": "file"
    }
     ],
     "code": 404,
     "message": "File not found: CAESABiCASCQ1OnN-VMoAA=="
     }
      }
```

It seems like this ID is not the id to find files.

There must be something I missed but i don't know what.

I am new to programming, especially to Google and Android and I would be very happy if any one can help me through their answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach.

1/ You can not use the DriveId for anything outside your Android App instance, you have to go for the **ResourceId** (see [SO 32210970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210970/list-files-from-google-drive-and-get-downloadurl-for-selected-file-in-android/32213123#32213123))

2/ The DriveId you're showing above is the 'preliminary' DriveId that is returned by GooPlaySvcs before the object is committed (uploaded) (see [SO 22874657](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269)). Also, you can't get a valid ResourceId until it the object is committed.

See also [SO 33355665](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355665/google-drive-android-api-invalid-driveid-and-null-resourceid/33356570#33356570), [SO 29030110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030110/cannot-get-folderid-that-i-just-created-on-google-drive/29049474#29049474)

If you intent to take the ResourceId 'outside' (to a different app), you'll be OK. If you decide to use this ResourceId in the same Android app, mixing the two Apis ([GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) and [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk)), you will potentially introduce latency issues, since GDAA is a 'buffering' layer between your app and the REST api (you've already run into one with your 'invalid' DriveId).

Good Luck