# google drive quota using android api for drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

How can I get the amount of storage and used quota of a user's google drive account? I'm building an android app with the android api for drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/.

I couldn't find any method that could return the details for me, but, I believe I have to use call the rest api like shown here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get. How do I retrieve the drive service instance? I already have mGoogleAuthClient which can talk to drive APIs. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient mGAC = new GoogleApiClient
  .Builder(this)
  .addApi(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.API)
  .addScope(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
  .setAccountName(email)
  .build(); 

com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGSvc = new Drive
  .Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(),
  GoogleAccountCredential
    .usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
    .setSelectedAccountName(email)
  ).build();
  }
```

gives you access to both the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) and the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Apis.

But remember a few things:

- [REST's *id* is GDAA's *ResourceID*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030110/cannot-get-folderid-that-i-just-created-on-google-drive/29049474#29049474)
- GDAA places a layer between your app and the Drive. This layer [extensively manages resources](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files) (caching, battery / bandwith, ...) resulting in latency beyond you direct control.

That means that mixing the two involves some timing [consideration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269).

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response. I tried using REST APIs in my android application but it's not working. I'm refering this sample code : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java. The reason of failure is `Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");` This authorize opens the browser in web application to authorize the user credentials but in Android browser is not opening for authenticaiton. This sample code works fine in web applicaiton.

Comment: I was referring to a native Android App,not Android browser. See these 2 demos the [GDAADemo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) and the [RESTDemo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.